# How to input two strings separated by new line in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

How can I input 2 strings which are separated by a new line?

My Problem:

First I need to give how many strings I need to get and then I need to get those strings then display it.

I tried this:

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    int n,i = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char arr[n][100];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%[^\n]s", arr[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**My Input is :**

```
2 I am
Aravind
```

**My Output is:**

```
I am
þ
```

First Line I got correct one but second line it shows some garbage value. Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have suggestions to not use `scanf`. However, if you 'must' use `scanf` then you can consider the following approach:

- For dynamic memory allocation you should use malloc
- the newline character stays in the stdin and hence needs to be flushed or handled/ignored

Here is the updated code.

```
int main()
{
    int n,i = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    scanf("%*[\n]"); 
    /*this will read the \n in stdin and not store it anywhere. So the next call to 
     * scanf will not be interfered with */

    char **inputs;
    inputs = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       inputs[i] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    }


    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%*[\n]");
        scanf("%100[^\n]", inputs[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", inputs[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have two major problems:

1. The `"%["` format ends with the closing `"]"`, there should be no `"s"` at the end.
2. The `"%["` format doesn't skip leading space, like that newline which will be present after the first line you read.

Both these issues can be easily solve by using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read whole lines instead.

Comment: Hi is there any other method apart from fgets?

Comment: @AravindEkan To read lines using standard C functions only, the best solution is `fgets`. You *can* use `scanf` (and family) but it becomes much more complex, and without a field-width limiter can also easily cause buffer overflows.

Comment: 3rd problem, no width limit.  `"%[^\n]"` is then akin to `gets()`.  Yes, better to use `fgets()`.

Answer (score -2):

use gets(arr[i]) instead of scanf.

Comment: Never *ever* use `gets`. [It's a dangerous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used), and has therefore been removed from the C standard (and was deprecated long before).